# PostgreSQL return 42P01 even after saving data in given table

Tags: php, postgresql, orm, slim, datamapper

I am using SPOT ORM and slim framework with PHP.

```
$new_payment["payment_method"] = 'paytm';
 $new_payment["created_at"] = $date;
        $new_payment["payment_link"] = $url;
        $new_payment["payment_status"] = "started";
        $new_payment["request_id"] = $request_id;
        $new_payment["qr_data"] = $qr_data;
        $new_payment["extra_data"] = $curlResponse->response;
        $new_payment["amount"] = $amount;
        $new_payment["machine_id"] = $machine_id;
    $payment_info = new Payment_Info($new_payment);
    $is_success = $this->spot->mapper("App\Payment_Info")->save($payment_info);
```

The above statements is saving the `$new_payment` object in the `payment_info` table but it is returning `status code:42P01`

My `Payment_Info` class-

```
    class Payment_Info extends \Spot\Entity
{
    protected static $table = "payment_info";

    public static function fields()
    {
        return [
            "payment_info_id" => ["type" => "bigint", "unsigned" => true, "primary" => true, "autoincrement" => true],//Primary key <tablename>_id 
            "created_at" => ["type" => "datetime", "required" => true, "value" => new \DateTime()], // Creation timestamp
            "payment_method" => ["type" => "string", "required" => true], // ["PayTm","UPI","MSwipe",etc]
            "payment_link" => ["type" => "text"], // payment link of selected method on which payment is done
            "payment_status" => ["type" => "string", "required" => true], // ["completed","cancelled"]
            "request_id" => ["type" => "bigint", "required" => true], //Request Id against which the payment info was generated
            "qr_data" => ["type" => "text"],//qr data or any other specific data that is requied to complete the payment
            "extra_data" => ["type" => "json_array"], //Extra data recieved after payment completion
            "amount" => ["type" => "float"], //Amount for which the payment info was generated
            "machine_id" => ["type" => "bigint", "required" => true]
        ];
    }

    public static function relations(Mapper $mapper, Entity $entity){
        return [
            "Request" => $mapper->belongsTo($entity, 'App\Request','request_id')
        ];
    }
}
```

Response I get:

```
Fatal error:  Uncaught InvalidArgumentException: Invalid HTTP status code in /Users/apple/Desktop/wendor/instabox-api/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/Http/Response.php:222
Stack trace:
#0 /Users/apple/Desktop/wendor/instabox-api/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/Http/Response.php(191): Slim\Http\Response->filterStatus('42P01')
#1 /Users/apple/Desktop/wendor/instabox-api/src/Slim/Handlers/ApiError.php(48): Slim\Http\Response->withStatus('42P01')
#2 [internal function]: Slim\Handlers\ApiError->__invoke(Object(Slim\Http\Request), Object(Slim\Http\Response), Object(PDOException))
#3 /Users/apple/Desktop/wendor/instabox-api/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/App.php(665): call_user_func_array(Object(Slim\Handlers\ApiError), Array)
#4 /Users/apple/Desktop/wendor/instabox-api/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/App.php(390): Slim\App->handleException(Object(PDOException), Object(Slim\Http\Request), Object(Slim\Http\Response))
#5 /Users/apple/Desktop/wendor/instabox-api/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/App.php(296): Slim\App->process(Object(Slim\Http\Request), Object(Slim\Http\Response))
in /Users/apple/Desktop/wendor/instabox-api/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/Http/Response.php on line 222
```

Comment: That error means "undefined table". Maybe you are trying to access a table that isn't there.

Comment: No, It is saving the data in the table that I mentioned but returns the above error.

Comment: Well, that's still what the error says. Trace the SQL statements, and you will find the reason.

Comment: I am using a sequence to auto increment the value of the primary key in the above table. Is it possible that PostgreSQL is not returning the data to SpotORM that it has saved the data in the table? And maybe that's why it is giving 42P01. Also, I am using the sequence for one more table and it also gives me the same response even after saving the data.

Comment: No idea. But the message very likely comes from the PostgreSQL server. So trace the SQL to see what statement fails, then maybe you have a clue.